# what's wrong with this SQL statement causing column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql table (migration_terms) fields are as follows

```
oldterm   count    newterm  seed
```

I used the following create table statment.

```
CREATE TABLE `migration_terms` 
    ( 
      `oldterm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
      `count` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0', 
      `newterm` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
      `seed` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY (`seed`) 
    )   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And It works, no problems there.

but then when I used the following `insert into` statement to populate it;

```
"INSERT INTO migration_terms 
     SELECT looseterm as oldterm, 
            COUNT(seed) AS count 
            FROM looseterms 
            GROUP BY looseterm 
            ORDER BY count DESC "
```

I get this error;

```
 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

I cannot figure out why?

If you need the table structure of the looseterms table, it was created by the following create table statement.

```
CREATE TABLE looseterms
(
     `seed` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     `looseterm` varchar(255)
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the columns if your select statement has fewer columns than the table

```
"INSERT INTO migration_terms 
        (oldterm, 
         count) 
SELECT looseterm   AS oldterm, 
       Count(seed) AS count 
FROM   looseterms 
GROUP  BY looseterm 
ORDER  BY count DESC  "
```

From [MySql docs on Insert Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

> If you do not specify a list of column names for INSERT ... VALUES or
>   INSERT ... SELECT, values for every column in the table must be
>   provided by the VALUES list or the SELECT statement. If you do not
>   know the order of the columns in the table, use DESCRIBE tbl_name to
>   find out.

Answer (score 4):

Your insert is adding 2 columns of data, whereas your table's definition has 4 columns